# Random orthogonal matrix

Tags: matrix

Is there a way to generate real random orthogonal matrices in mathematica? If Q is an orthogonal matrix, it's properties are

[image: dd]

Comment: Have a look at `Orthogonalize`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]]` should do the trick for $n \times n$ matrices. Very obscure name IMHO.

Comment: Can I fix the random matrix once produced

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Of course, you can store the result in a variable: `A = RandomVariate[CircularRealMatrixDistribution[n]]` and use `A` from then on. If you want to have reproducible pseudorandom matrices, you can use `SeedRandom` to set a seed for the random number generator.

Comment: What I meant is seedrandom. Do I just add seed before random

Comment: "Do I just add seed before random " Yes. See also the documentation.

Comment: I would like to know if there is any way to rescale all the elements of the resulting matrix so that they like in a given interval, say $[-r,r]$ as specified by the user. I realised that the ```CircularRealMatrixDistribution``` ensures that the elements are in the interval $[-1,1]$ but I wanted the same for a general interval.

Comment: Re: _"Very obscure name IMHO."_ Dyson coined the term  _circular unitary ensemble._ "Circular" because the eigenphases are uniformly distributed on the unit circle, and "unitary" because these are matrices from $U(n)$.  A natural name for the ensemble of real orthogonal matrices would be _circular orthogonal ensemble_, but that name is already taken [Dyson used it for the quotient $U(n)/O(n)$ rather than for the group $O(n)$ itself]. _Circular real ensemble_ was the alternative name proposed [in the context of a physics problem](https://arxiv.org/abs/1004.2438) and then adopted by Mathematica.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker Thanks for the comment. Nonetheless, I think that the term `UniformOrthogonalMatrixDistribution` or something containing "Haar measure" would have been more expressive.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pedestrian way of getting a real orthogonal random matrix:

The eigenvalues of an orthogonal matrix are +1 or -1. Therefore, we may create a diagonal matrix with +1 or -1 on the diagonal and the rotate this matrix by a random rotation:

```
n = 3;
mat0 = DiagonalMatrix[RandomChoice[{-1, 1}, n]];
rot = RotationMatrix[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, n}]];
mat1 = Transpose[rot].mat0.rot;
OrthogonalMatrixQ[mat1]
```

(* True *)

Comment: Are you sure you're sampling from a [uniform distribution in orthogonal-matrix-space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) here?

Comment: What is the objection?

Comment: My objection is that if I execute your recipe many times and plot the spatial distribution of the eigenvectors of the resulting matrices, I do not get a uniform distribution.

Comment: Interestingly that is true. Do you have an explanation?

Comment: (1) you're pulling the 3D coordinates from a cube instead of a sphere; should be `RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[], {2, n}]` instead of `RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {2, n}]`.
(2) I don't think `RotationMatrix` does the right thing here.

Comment: Yes, of course. Thank you.